# WAMP Test Server and magento

Tags: magento, wampserver

I already have a website with magento but I never created a test server which I want to do now.  I downloaded WAMP to use as a test server, i put all my files to the /www folder but when I go to the localhost I am getting a log error.

Basically I don't know how to transfer the website files to WAMP.  The website is set up with Magento.  When I was transfering all the files I would receive an error message saying Mage.php file was not found.

Comment: You're really gonna have to provide more detail, there's not much we can do with such generic information.

Comment: Did you copy the .htaccess file from the web root as well?

Comment: Yes it was transfered as well

Comment: There's a lot more to setting up your WAMP environment than just copying the files.  .htaccess could be a problem. Paths.  The core config table needs to be updated.  ...

Comment: this question really should be on serverfault.com, it's not related to progamming unless you can provide more information to demonstrate that it is...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use something like VirtualBox and setup a Linux environment and not WAMP and use the following guide:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server